# Power BI with ggplot in python

Tags: python-3.x, powerbi, python-ggplot

I have created below code in python for Power BI. This is not showing anything.

```
    # The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

    # dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Company, Target)
    # dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

    # Paste or type your script code here:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    from plotnine import *
    from plotnine.data import mpg

    (ggplot(dataset)         # data 
     + aes(x='Company')    # variable 
     + geom_bar(size=20)) # ype of plot 

    plt.show()
```

Comment: are you sure that the python code i correct? it looks strange.

Comment: this is correct as there is not error when I am running. I am writing this in the Power BI python control.